# On orthonormal basis of scalar products

Tags: linear-algebra

For **x** and **y** in $R^2$ we have: $$(x,y)= x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + kx_1y_2 + kx_2y_1$$ where k is a real parameter. Give an example of orthonormal basis for this scalar product. 
$$$$ 
I don't understand this question. Aren't orthonormal basis created in a way to give out the canonical product i.e., the dot product by definition? Can some please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to come with an orthonormal basis relative to the given inner product, not the usual inner product. You  can start with $(1,0)$ and calculate its norm. You will get $\|(1,0)\|=1$. Then try to find $(x,y)$ such that  its inner product with $(1,0)$ is $0$. One such vector is $(x,y)=(1,-\frac 1 k)$. Then you have to normalize it so that it becomes a unit vector. You will end up with the orthonormal basis $\{(1,0), \frac  1 c(1,-\frac 1 k)\}$ where $c=\sqrt {\frac 1 {k^{2}-1}}$. Note the given expression defines an inner product only when $|k|<1$.

Comment: Can you explain the normalization a bit more? I'm getting $c=\sqrt(\frac{1}{k^2} -1)$

Answer (score 0):

You have to find $x,y \in \mathbb R^2$ such that

1. $(x,x)=(y,y)=1$.

and

2. $(x,y)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

An orthonormal basis is defined with respect to particular inner product. That is, given a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$, an inner product structure is a map $V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfying certain conditions (bilinearity, symmetry, etc).

In this case, we have $V = \mathbb R^2$, and we are given the inner product $$f: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb R \quad f(\vec x, \vec y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + k x_1y_2 + kx_2y_1$$

Note that from the inner product, we can define the length/metric as $||\vec x|| \equiv \sqrt{f(\vec x, \vec x)}$.

That is, the norm of the vector is the square root of the dot product of a vector with itself.

Now, we are to find two vectors $\vec x, \vec y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

1. $||x|| = 1$
2. $ ||y|| = 1$
3. $ f(x, y) = 0$

Let's go through the conditions and see what we need.

\begin{align*}
&||x|| = 1 \\
&\sqrt{f(x, x)} = 1 \\
&f(x, x) = 1 \quad \text{square on both sides}\\ 
&x_1x_1 + x_2x_2 + kx_1x_2 + kx_2x_1 = 1 \quad \text{use $f$ definition}\\
&x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 2kx_1x_2 = 1 \\
\end{align*}

Similarly, for $||y|| = 1$, we get the condition:
\begin{align*}
&y_1^2 + y_2^2 + 2ky_1y_2 = 1
\end{align*}

From the last condition, we get
\begin{align*}
x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + k(x_1y_2 + x_2y_1) = 0
\end{align*}